# database migration error in Yii

Tags: yii

I am newbie to yii. I have made database in MySQL.After that I want to migrate the database.So for that I made a folder called migration under protected and from framework folder  whenever I am writing command `yiic migrate create --name=add_table` in terminal.It is showing error like `yiic: command not found`
I am using ubuntu 11.04.So what is the problem behind that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cd down to the folder containing the yiic file and try the command then.  If that doesn't work try to put "php" in front of the command like:

```
php yiic migrate create --name=add_table
```

Or you could try:

```
./yiic
```

Comment: hey I got the error . I just used ./yiic migrate create _tablename from the current directory and the migration was successful.

Comment: thanks had a similar problem but the ./ before the yiic command worked